# Come tradurre le varie tipologie di registrazione ad un evento (Early - Normal - Late)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation, single-words

Buongiorno!

Come posso tradurre in italiano i diversi tipi di registrazione per un evento?

**Early registration** (a volte mostrato anche come Early birds)

**Normal registration**

**Late registration**

Grazie!

Comment: A costo di essere pedante: senz'altro “registrazione” in questo senso è ampiamente entrato nell'uso, ma siamo sicuri che si dica effettivamente così e che non sia un calco dall'inglese (come chi dice “sottomettere” per intendere *submit*, cioè “sottoporre”, “presentare”)? A me suona meglio “iscrizione”, per esempio.

Comment: Ottima osservazione. E come tradurresti Early - Normal - Late?

Comment: Iscrizione anticipata - Iscrizione normale - Iscrizione tardiva possono andare secondo te?

Comment: *Late* e *early* sono sempre rognosi... :) Mi sembra che le tue proposte suonino bene, anche se forse “tardiva” un po' meno. Butto lì un “in ritardo” e “all'ultimo momento”, ma confido in altri interventi.

Comment: Di nuovo il pedante (non mi odiare, johnny): che ti aveva fatto di male “tipi” e come mai l'hai corretto in “tipologie”?

Comment: Volevo migliorare il titolo. Posso rimettere come prima in caso.

Comment: Personalmente, e ovviamente senza nulla di personale nei tuoi confronti, trovo che “tipologia” sia una di quelle parole inutili, lievemente ostentate, con troppe sillabe, come “problematica” al posto di “problema”, “tematica” per “tema”, “ottimale” per “ottimo”, “utilizzazione” per “uso” (o al limite “utilizzo”) e così via, di cui si può benissimo fare a meno.

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHAHHAAH!!! ma Po è un fiume italiano mentre "un pò" indica "un poco"
Corretta la traduzione di Early-Normal-Late come Anticipata-Regolare-Ritardata

Comment: Questo mi sembra più un commento che una risposta vera e propria.

Comment: si putroppo non ho ancora 50 di reputation e faceva un pò ridere DaG che correggeva Marcelo dicendogli che si dice "po" e non "pò" :D

Comment: ah ho capito. In realta' nel suo commento c'e' un apostrofo dopo "po". Pero' si fa un po' fatica a vedere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao!

Potresti dire:

- registrazione anticipata
- registrazione normale
- registrazione tardiva

Però le parole esatte dipendono un po' dal contesto.

Comment: Si scrive “po'”, non “pò”. Vedi il mio commento a una tua altra risposta.